# How can I unregister a WebViewReceiver in a WebView?

Tags: android, webview

guys.

I use a WebView in my android app, 
but when I close the activity that uses it, 
it will always gives me an exception in the logcat:

```
 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity XXXViewActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.webkit.WebView$WebViewReceiver@4182eab0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I checked the android src of android.webkit.WebView, but found no WebViewReceiver, so what's the problem?

Some of my code:

```
webView = new MmsWebView(this, mid);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webView.setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(true); 
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, mmsBody, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
...
...
public class MmsWebView extends WebView {
  private final Context context;
  private final int mid;
  public MmsWebView(Context context, int mid) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.mid = mid; 
    init();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding the `onDestroy()`? If so, are you invoking `super.onDestroy`?

Comment: yes, I do and also invoke super.onDestroy();